# Fixed navbar content to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project where I run through a small issue where I can't find a good solution for.

So what the idea is: You have a nav bar what is fixed. You need to scroll inside it and when you click on the button the content in the middle goes to right with a small part outside the navbar.

At first I thought I just add

```
  overflow-y: auto;
```

To my navbar but apprently this doesn't work and clips all the content.

I have created a codepen to show my problem.

http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/VjQBXA

Comment: you have answer right in your question.
remove (height:100vh;  overflow-y: auto;) this from sidebar and add it to item class.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because you're trying to set the height to match the window, but you also have some padding. You can use `box-sizing:border-box` to make the padding included in the specified height.

```js
var $item = $('.item'),
  $button = $('.button');

for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  $item.append(i + '<br>')
}

$button.on("click", function() {
  $item.toggleClass('addMargin');
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.addMargin {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
.item {
  transition: margin-left 1s cubic-bezier(0.36, -0.48, 0, 2.22);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="button">test</button>
  <div class="item">
  </div </div>
```